# mysql group by member from comma seperated string

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with over a million rows:

```
id | names
1  | sarah johnson
2  | anna smith;deborah cuoco
3  | sarah johnson;anna smith
```

I want to perform a single query which will return

```
name          | occurences
sarah johnson | 2
anna smith    | 2
deborah cuoco | 1
```

If it wasn't for "names" sometimes containing more than one entry then it would be as simple as:

```
SELECT names, count(id) as occurences
FROM table
GROUP BY names
ORDER BY occurences DESC
```

But I don't know how to handle this with "names" containing multiple values seperated in this case by semi-columns

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Comment: You should really reconsider your storage format by normalizing your data. Instead of storing all names in single column as comma-separated, create following tables: `user` table in which every row contains just single name, and link table which will contain rows with `user_id` linking to user table. This way your queries will become much simpler and will be indexable. Note that you cannot effectively index data in your current format, so it will be always slow

Comment: yea i've decided to do exactly this.. i didn't design this table initially it came from a huge 2gb csv dump.. I was trying to cut corners but I guess I have no choice. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

If you have just a handful of such names in any row, you can get them out with some manipulation:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(t.names, ';', n.n), ';', -1) as name,
       count(*) as occurences
FROM table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
WHERE n.n <= length(t.names) - length(replace(t.names, ';', '')) + 1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY occurences DESC;
```

This extracts the nth element from the name string.  The `where` clause makes sure that the only `x` elements are extracted for a string with `x` elements (otherwise, the last one gets overcounted).  The above works for up to three names in `names`.

Comment: ty for trying but this doesn't seem to be working. First it throws an error "unknown column name in where clause". For some reason it isn't allowing to use the alias in the where clause. If I repeat the `substring_index(substring_index(names, ';', n.n), ';', -1)` instead then the query works but it overcounts the last name whenever there are 2 elements